# How do I create an integer array that outputs 3 different numbers?

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I want to create an int array that hold `10` numbers that range from (`0-9`). Then I want the array to output `3` different numbers.

I made one but it only gives me one random number.
How can I fix this so it outputs three numbers instead of one.

```
 int[] password = { 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };

 Random r = new Random();
 int inputPassword = r.Next(password.Length);
 Console.WriteLine(inputPassword);
```

Comment: Unless I've missed something, why don't you just use a loop of some kind?

Comment: loop so that it calls Next() as many times as you need. BTW I assume you realise this code doesn't actually use any of the numbers in the array?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the array to output"? What does it mean that an array outputs 3 numbers? If your question is "My program outputs 1 random number, but I want 3", perhaps you should repeat the code that outputs a number 3 times in a loop? Please note that you're not actually using the contents of the array, only its length. It just so happens that the random number generator will pick a number between 0 and 10 (not including the 10), if your array contained 100-109, you would still see outputs of 0-9. You need `WriteLine(password[inputPassword])` to get a number from the array.

Comment: https://www.dotnetperls.com/for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to achieve your aim is simple, use a loop of some kind.

In the example below I've used a `for` loop:

```
int[] password = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    int inputPassword = r.Next(password.Length);
    Console.WriteLine(inputPassword);
}
```

Incidentally, as pointed out by @ADyson, you're not actually using any of the stored values in your `password` array.  The line where you use the `Next` random should be like this:

```
int inputPassword = password[r.Next(password.Length)];
```

This will fetch the value at a random `index` in the `password` array.

Answer (score 1):

Unless, at some point, you are planning to change the numbers in the array to something different, then the array is completely unnecessary - other than its length property, which is fixed, you aren't actually using it.

Based on what you've stated as your goal, the code could be as simple as this:

```
int n = 10;
int length = 3;
Random r = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    int inputPassword = r.Next(n);
    Console.WriteLine(inputPassword);
}
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/OKgqIE

P.S. If there are more constraints to the scenario which make this inadequate then you need to clarify them.